# Store view with messed up CSS

Tags: javascript, css, store-view

I have set up a German view in addition to the current default view and the css is messed up when I change the language. It looks like it goes into mobile mode. The website is http://m.theseolounge.co.uk/
Do I need to change the Base Skin URL and Base Media URL? At present I am using the store default. Any pointer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://m.theseolounge.co.uk/skin/frontend/base/default/css/_config/grid_german.css"


"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://m.theseolounge.co.uk/skin/frontend/base/default/css/_config/layout_german.css"


"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://m.theseolounge.co.uk/skin/frontend/base/default/css/_config/design_german.css"
```

Above 4 css not found in your theme please update this 4 theme or copy from your base theme and rename those theme as above name and might be your problem solve

Comment: Good grief! Basically it's changing dynamically the name of the theme's css files! They are grid_default.css, layout_default.css and design_default.css. Sot it's a configuration problem

Comment: Might be your theme has some configuaration  in system->configuartion please check at store level also for this problem